# When changing the image resourse the image size changes

Tags: android, onclick, imagebutton, layoutparams

I have an `OnclickListener` in my Android app which changes the `ImageResourse` when clicking the element assigned to it, the problem is when changing the `ImageResourse` the size of it changes also(fills the height of the Layout and widen the width) and the old image still exists in the background, look at the following Image:

[image]

This is my code:

```
 lp_ineer_ver = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER);
 lp_ineer_ver.bottomMargin = 2;
 lp_ineer_ver.leftMargin = 12;
 lp_ineer_ver.topMargin = 2;

 ImageButton rgp1 = new ImageButton(this);
 icon1.addView(rgp1);
 rgp1.setLayoutParams(lp_ineer_ver);
 rgp1.setImageResource(R.drawable.grp);
 rgp1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
 rgp1.setTag(current_status);
 assignListener(rgp1);

public void assignListener(final ImageButton image) {
            image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String tag = image.getTag().toString().trim();
                    if(tag.equals(current_status) || tag.equals(on)){
                        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home_grpbuttonfocus0); 
                        image.setTag(off);
                    }else if(tag.equals(off)){
                        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home_grpbuttonfocus10); 
                        image.setTag(on);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

I tried to change the Width and Height to wrap content but this didn't work, also i tried to set the `ImageButton` params again when clicking but didn't work, and also tried to deal once with the `ImageButton` directly and other with the clicked view but also didn't work.

Comment: Brother while you are clicking the layout param set as mach parent which mentioned in class

Comment: @RavindMaurya I changed it WrapContent but it still changes the size

Comment: Plz check the sizes of both screen in terms of height and width are same or not

Comment: @MRefaat you must set your ImageButton's size to fixed like 200dp, 300dp, or use "match_parent" attribute if your Button's parent's size is fixed

Comment: Try to use setImageResource(R.drawable. )

Comment: @Alex that worked, you can add it as answer